# How can I click a link but not refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how can I use ajax with links and not refreshing the page? This code shows the links of brands

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="offer-tabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="offerTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" >
          <a class="nav-link active" id="all-tab"   href="accueil2.php?r=All"  >Toutes les marques</a>
            <?php 
            $query="select * from marque";
            $query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            ?>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" >
          <a class="nav-link brand"   href="accueil2.php?ro=<?php echo $row['id_marque'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a> 
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: do you want open link on the new page? if you want this you can add target="_blank" on the a tag

Comment: no i want  the same page

Comment: you can send ajax request to the server for specific link and then change the body of the page with the response. Or you can use for example node.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look into javascript on the client.

For the following HTML:

```html
<div>
 <a id="someId">Get data</a>
</div>
```

```js
// Find the element
const link = document.getElementById("someId");
// attach an onclick listener
link.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the navigation
  // Get data
  const response = await fetch(`/accueil2.php?ro${id_marque}`);
  // Convert data to usable text
  const data = await response.text();
  
  // Replace the contents of the div
  link.parentElement.innerHtml = data;
};
```

This is not the best way perse, but I believe it achieves what you want. You'll have to get the id_marque as a variable from somewhere.

Comment: it still reload

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you asked... But if you want to open a link in a new tab, just add the `target` argument at your `<a>` element, using the `_blank` value.

E.g.

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, `<li>` was generating a refresh. I add the symbol # in the href and that avoid the page refresh:

1. This `<li>` generate a page refresh:

`<li><a onclick="function();" href="">something</a></li>`

2. This `<li>` with "#" do not generate a page refresh:

`<li><a onclick="function();" href="#">something</a></li>`